# Combining numeric data with factors in R

Tags: r, histogram, bar-chart

Beforehand there is to be said that I am completly new to R.

I need assistance in dealing with the following:
A table consists of several columns, however just two ('Type' and 'Percentage of the Landscape') are relevant for me.
I would like to display the 'Percentage of the Landscape' (numeric) in conjunction with the 'Type' (factor) in a histogram or in a barplot, if possible.
Mainly I'd would like to display the "Type" on the x-axis (see picture below).

```
 'data.frame':   9 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ TYPE                   : Factor w/ 9 levels " Broad-leaved forest ",..: 2 3 7 5 6 4 9 8 1
 $ Total.Area             : int  1939 141 358 74 64 102 69 18 2
 $ Percantage.of.Landscape: num  69.25 5.04 12.79 2.64 2.29 ...
 $ Edge.Density           : num  19.36 4.29 8.93 2.5 3 ...
 $ X                      : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ X.1                    : logi  NA NA NA NA NA NA ...

> levels(data$TYPE)
[1] " Broad-leaved forest "                      " Coniferous forest "                       
[3] " Discontinuous urban fabric "               " Inland marshes "                          
[5] " Land principally occupied by agriculture " " Mineral extraction sites "                
[7] " Mixed forest "                             " Non-irrigated arable land "               
[9] " Pastures "                                
> str(data$Percantage.of.Landscape)
 num [1:9] 69.25 5.04 12.79 2.64 2.29 ...
> data$Percantage.of.Landscape
[1] 69.2500  5.0357 12.7857  2.6429  2.2857  3.6429  2.4643  0.6429  0.0714
```

[image]

Comment: `barplot(height = data$Percantage.of.Landscape, names.arg = data$TYPE)` [sic]

Comment: In the future, it's good to share your attempt at solving the problem, rather than *just* the data. `dput()` is a great way to share data - it's copy/pasteable. In this case, since only two columns are relevant, `dput(data[, c(1, 3)])` would have been a perfect way to share the data.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. I just didnt't know how much information you need to help me solving this problem.

Comment: By the way, thank you for your suggested solution.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your data looks as follows?

```
percentage <- c(69.2500, 5.0357, 12.7857, 2.6429, 2.2857, 3.6429, 2.4643, 0.6429, 0.0714)
type <- as.factor(c("Broad-leaved forest", 
          " Coniferous forest", 
          "Discontinuous urban fabric", 
          "Inland marshes", 
          "Land principally occupied by agriculture", 
          "Mineral extraction sites", 
          "Mixed forest", 
          "Non-irrigated arable land", 
          "Pastures"))
other_variable1 <- 1:9
other_variable2 <- 13:5

data <- data.frame(percentage,
                   type,
                   other_variable1,
                   other_variable2)
```

Then you can just do a simple barplot like this:

```
barplot(data$percentage,
        names.arg = data$type)
```